# Creating dataframe by adjusting the index taken from list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a dataframe from the following list of tuples. The first item in the tuple is `ID`, second `values` is a list of values and the third is the `lag`. This `lag` defines how many indices I need to shift in either direction of the first tuple to get the dataframe.

```
mytup = [(111, [1,2,3,4,5], 0), (222, [33,44,55,66], 2), (333, [0,11,22,33], -1)]


ID  values           lag
111 1,2,3,4,5        0
222 33,44,55,66      2
333 0,11,22,33      -1
```

The result that is created as dataframe is given below. The first row is the header in this dataframe. The `lag` is always in reference to the first column (`111`).

```
111 222 333
nan nan 0
1   nan 11
2   nan 22
3   33  33
4   44  nan
5   55  nan
nan 66  nan
```

The way I want to populate the dataframe is to start with first tuple. Then I take one tuple from the rest, one at a time and populate the dataframe introducing `nan`.

I will have this in dataframe once I have already seen the second tuple:

```
111    222
1   nan
2   nan
3   33
4   44
5   55
nan 66
```

The third tuple has negative lag of `-1` , therefore I want the previous dataframe to move down one position and create the final dataframe which I reproduce again.

```
111 222 333
nan nan 0
1   nan 11
2   nan 22
3   33  33
4   44  nan
5   55  nan
nan 66  nan
```

Edit:

As @cphlewis pointed out, the output will be dependent on the order in which columns are added. In my case the lag is always relative to the first (original) vector. Therefore, the final result will remain same irrespective of the order.

Comment: This algorithm is column-order-specific, it seems: if I do it to 111, 333, 222 in that order I get data columns [nan, 1,2,3,4,5], [0,11,22,33,nan,nan], [nan,nan,33,44,55,66]. All the data, columns 222 and 333 are offset as required, but it isn't even the same size as the output in the first order. Do I have the algorithm right?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the first column `111`  is always the reference.  the `lag` is in reference to the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this (from the pandas.Series docstring):

> Operations between Series (+, -, /, *, **) align values based on their
>   associated index values-- they need not be the same length. The result
>   index will be the sorted union of the two indexes.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import arange
#mytup = [(111, [1,2,3,4,5], 0), (222, [33,44,55,66], 2), (333, [0,11,22,33], -1)]
mytup = [(111, [1,2,3,4,5], 0),
         (222, [33,44,55,66], 2),
         (444, [1,2,3,4,5], 0),
         (333, [0,11,22,33], -1),
         ('a', [5,6,7], -2)]

def SfromTuple(row):
    name, data, shift = row
    return pd.Series(data, index = arange(shift, len(data) + shift))

reindexed = pd.concat([SfromTuple(row) for row in mytup], axis=1)
reindexed.columns = [x[0] for x in mytup]
print(reindexed)
```

result from original `mytup`:

> ```
> 0   111  222  333
> -1  NaN  NaN    0
>  0    1  NaN   11
>  1    2  NaN   22
>  2    3   33   33
>  3    4   44  NaN
>  4    5   55  NaN
>  5  NaN   66  NaN
> ```

from the longer `mytup` added above:

> ```
> 0   111  222  444  333   a
> -2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   5
> -1  NaN  NaN  NaN    0   6
>  0    1  NaN    1   11   7
>  1    2  NaN    2   22 NaN
>  2    3   33    3   33 NaN
>  3    4   44    4  NaN NaN
>  4    5   55    5  NaN NaN
>  5  NaN   66  NaN  NaN NaN
> ```

Comment: Somehow this is not working when I add one more item into `mytup`. It always gives me three column. For example when `mytup = [(111, [1,2,3,4,5], 0), (222, [33,44,55,66], 2), (333, [0,11,22,33], -1), (444, [1,2,3,4,5], 0)]`, the result produce just 3 columns.

Comment: ... yeah, that's unexpected; the `raw` df is right, but `map(newSeries, raw)` fails. Can't see why! Rearranging `mytup` entries isn't informative...

Comment: Okay, map over a df is apparently creaky, but DataFrames have a bunch of useful iter-types and using one of *those* works. (As did `map(fn, roo.index)`.)